# File upload via FTP error

Tags: php, file, ftp, copy

Code:

```
$file = '/export/clients.xml';
$remote_file = '/clients.xml';
$ftp_server = "ftp://my.address.com";
$ftp_user_name = "user";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Now the original file path is: ftp://my@address.com/domains/website.com/public_html/export/clients.xml

How should I write the file path so that it could complete the file transfer? I want the file to be copied into the root directory of my FTP server. But it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was FTP server name. I removed the ftp:// part and now it's working.